# sample.vue:957 THREE.Euler: .setFromRotationMatrix() encountered an unknown order: NaN

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sv7w.png)
sample.vue:957 THREE.Euler: .setFromRotationMatrix() encountered an unknown order: NaN

I have copied the camera's initialization data and need to drag and animate the model perspective back to its initialization state, but quaternion alerts me. Why?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.